# 403 Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while globbing file pattern

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I have created the table in bigquery with G-Drive file link, then to insert the data automatically into another table I am using Google cloud function. Here I am facing some permission error,

Error: 403 Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while globbing file pattern

How to overcome of this problem. Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the service account used by the cloud function has proper access to the file as well as BigQuery.